# Is there a better/faster way to find unique value count for a data frame than df.nunique()? (Python pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I noticed that df.nunique() roughly scales linearly with data size. I am wondering if there is a solution that would be better as data size increases? Here's an example, let me know if you can come up with a faster approach!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def createList(r1, r2):
    """ creates a list of values given a range.
    ex. createList(1,3) == [1, 2, 3]
    """
    return np.arange(r1, r2+1, 1)

   sample_df = pd.DataFrame(
   data = {
        'a' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'b' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'c' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'd' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'e' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'f' : createList(1, 50_000_000),
        'g' : createList(1, 50_000_000),

    }
)

sample_df.nunique()
```

When I ran %%timeit in jupyter notebooks here are the times I got

```
sample_df.nunique() # with 50_000_000, 10.5 s ± 3.05 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

sample_df.nunique() # with 100_000_000, 21.2 s ± 6.16 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

In *this particular* case, I found this to be faster:

```
sample_df.apply(lambda S: len(np.unique(S.values)))
```

And it will be faster, e.g.:

```
In [16]: sample_df = pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     data = {
    ...:         'a' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'b' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'c' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'd' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'e' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'f' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:         'g' : np.arange(1, 50_000_000+1),
    ...:     }
    ...: )

In [17]: %timeit sample_df.nunique()
25.4 s ± 919 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [18]: %timeit sample_df.apply(lambda S: len(np.unique(S.values)))
6.37 s ± 63.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```